# What is a strategy to earn the Elite AI Romp achievement?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Winning 100 matches to earn the Elite AI Romp seems like a difficult achievement to earn: not only because of the time involved, but because of the skill of Elite AI opponents.

What is a strategy to earn the Elite AI Romp achievement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While winning 100 "fair" matches against an Elite AI opponent might earn the player a sense of satisfaction, the easiest and quickest way to earn the Elite (formerly Insane) AI Romp achievement is to simply grind it out.

The strategy employed by Elite Terran AI opponents is especially susceptible to a [Proxy 2 Gate](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Chrono_Boost) all-in strategy. Following the below steps on [Agria Valley](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Agria_Valley) or another 1v1 map should consistently net a win:

1. Probes should immediately begin to harvest minerals.
2. Build a Probe.
3. Set Nexus to a Control Group.
4. Build another Probe.
5. After Probe is built send a Probe to just outside of enemy base location.
6. While Probe is moving towards enemy base build another Probe (maxing out supply).
7. Once Probe is outside enemy base warp in a Pylon.
8. Once Pylon has arrived warp in 2 Gateways.
9. Send Probe back to main base.
10. Have returning Probe build a Pylon in main base then shift right click minerals.
11. Once Gateways are warped in start cranking out Zealots and attacking the Terran base.
12. Use the Nexus's [Chrono Boost](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Chrono_Boost) ability to speed up production of Zealots.
13. Wait for your Terran opponent to GG.

Between setup and game play each match will take around 5 minutes. When you do the math, earning this achievement will take more than 8 hours of repetitive slaughtering. Thankfully earning the elite version will also earn you the medium and harder achievements.

Comment: I seem to remember in WoL as Protoss you could also do a photon cannon cheese.  Similar to your strategy, just keep making photons and pylons moving close to the enemy supply lines.  Pump drones in your base and just cover their base with cannons and it's a quick GG.

Comment: @turbo I have never tried the photon cannon cheese though it would might work as well. There have been tweaks to the AI strategies since WoL and thus far the above works HoTS.

Comment: I haven't played much since WoL so it could no longer be true, just sounded very similar so I figured I'd offer it, I think it left more room for error too.

Comment: I watch 3 seasons of Supernatural back in WoL getting this achievement and the once for each race.

Comment: Cannon rush is suboptimal. Insane AIs, last I checked, cheat in two ways: they mine 7 minerals per trip, and they see all of their main base high ground. Since that visibility buff, you have to start your cannon push from the low ground, and while this is doable on Agria, proxy 2 Gate is still faster.

Comment: @OrcJMR didn't know they added that, good to know

Comment: @turbo I haven't played since early 2011, so things may have changed.

Answer (score 4):

In WoL there was another nice tactic for ZvZ, which also fit under 5 minutes.

In short you should go 7-pool, and around 9 supply send two drones two your opponents base. They should get there more or less by the time the pool is finished.

[image: buildings location]

There's a bug in AI that will cause the drones to not attack the spine crawler at once. Instead, they will get stucked between the minerals. So place your first spine crawler in the red square, and the second one on the second X mark. Just **don't block the entry, place it a bit to the outside.** Don't worry, they won't come through.

Now, this is obviously enough to win, but if you want to speed things up, send out a 3rd drone when the first two are halfway. The 3rd spine crawler should be placed in range of both already there, and will make the PC GG around 4:30.

Comment: Cheesy as hell ;)

Answer (score 1):

Proxy spines in mineral line. The elite AI will micro workers to attack your spines however you can eliminate that by bringing lings:

8 pool, stop drones, build 2 zerglings then send 2 drones accompanied by the zerglings.

Plant your spines as suggested then when workers attack your spines attack move your 4 zerglings towards the workers, the workers attack priority list will change and they come to attack the zerglings then you run off and repeat, the workers get stuck in limbo running from spine to zerglings and back until the spines complete.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Answers should be able to stand on their own without referencing other answers.

Answer (score 0):

There used to also be a scam where you can start building on their gas as zerg, causing all the drones to attack. Then you cancel before complete or death and repeat. This cripples their economy.

Comment: Does this still work?